Getting @mocked error after updating mockito version form 1.9 to 1.20
I'm getting error "cannot find this symbol
Symbol : method value()
location : @interface mockit.Mocked" in this line
@mockito ({"()", "getAuthenticatorMgmtSoap(URL)"}) AuthenticatorMGMLocator authenticatorMgmServiceLocator;
Do I need to replace this mocked annotation?
